# Linker script: allocation of .bss section

Tags: c++, ld, linker-scripts

I have a linker script like this:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(binary)
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0xFFFF800000000000 ;
    .startup_text : { processor.o(.text) }
    .text : { *(EXCLUDE_FILE (processor.o) .text) }
    .data : { *(.data) }
    .rodata : { *(.rodata) }
    linker_first_free_page = ALIGN(4096);
}
```

A piece of code loads the executable generated by this script, printing these infos:

```
size of executable (pages)    3
first free page               0xffff800000003000
```

And the executable itself prints:

```
&(linker_first_free_page)     0xffff800000003000
```

So everything works good so far. Now my executable needs a `.bss` section. Note that I don't have a loader capable of loading elf files, so I need a flat binary that can be just read and used, with all sections inside.

**First attempt**

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(binary)
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0xFFFF800000000000 ;
    .startup_text : { processor.o(.text) }
    .text : { *(EXCLUDE_FILE (processor.o) .text) }
    .data : { *(.data) }
    .rodata : { *(.rodata) }
    .bss : { *(.bss) }
    linker_first_free_page = ALIGN(4096);
}
```

That is, simply adding a `.bss` section. This is the output:

```
size of executable (pages)    3
first free page               0xffff800000003000
&(linker_first_free_page)     0xffff800000004000
```

That is, the linker variable is correctly updated, but the section is not allocated (I guess this is pretty normal for a `.bss` section).

**Second attempt**

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(binary)
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0xFFFF800000000000 ;
    .startup_text : { processor.o(.text) }
    .text : { *(EXCLUDE_FILE (processor.o) .text) }
    .data : { *(.data) *(.bss) }
    .rodata : { *(.rodata) }
    linker_first_free_page = ALIGN(4096);
}
```

That is, putting `.bss` section inside the `.data` one. This is the output:

```
size of executable (pages)    4
first free page               0xffff800000004000
&(linker_first_free_page)     0xffff800000003000
```

That is, the `.bss` is allocated, but the linker variable is not updated (and I can't understand why...)

**Short question**

So, given all above, how can I embed the `.bss` section in a flat binary, so that it can be loaded in memory like a "standard" file and used directly, without a specific loader?

Comment: The _BSS_ section generally isn't read from the file. By default _BSS_ falls at the end of the address space of the binary file. This means you don't generally need the _BSS_ region inside the file. Since you are trying to do it this way, a kludge might be to define _BSS_ right after _DATA_ section in the linker script, and update the location counter using SIZEOF. Something like `.bss : { *(.bss) }` followed by `. = . + SIZEOF(.bss);`

Comment: @michaelpetch thanks for the idea. Could be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [comment by Michael Petch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997577/linker-script-allocation-of-bss-section#comment57735654_34997577) gave me the insight for the answer:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(binary)
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0xFFFF800000000000 ;
    .startup_text : { processor.o(.text) }
    .text : { *(EXCLUDE_FILE (processor.o) .text) }
    .data : { *(.data) }
    .rodata : { *(.rodata) }
    .bss : { *(.bss) }
    .fake : { . = . + SIZEOF(.bss); }
    linker_first_free_page = ALIGN(4096);
}
```